# Display Java code in html page

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting

How to display java code in a html page? I tried with `<pre>` tag, but syntax highlighting is not happening properly. `<pre>` tag just maintains the spaces and tabs as it is given.

Got few options from net for syntax highlighting like prettify, syntax highlighter etc..
With prettify and syntax highlighter, few javascript and css files need to be downloaded and added to the application and java code should be given inside `<pre>`, but result is not as expected. code is displayed just as a text with given spaces, not as a java code.

Comment: what option are you trying to use, and how is your page set up to consume that option?

Comment: This is less a [tag:java] question and much more likely a [tag:HTML] and [tag:CSS] question. It's also a very broad question.

Answer (score 9):

Read [the Prettify getting started guide](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted).

To use Prettify, you first have to include the JavaScript code in your document:

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

Then, you have to use the "prettyprint" CSS class in your pre blocks:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">...</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua... I tried with this script link, it worked fine. Now I am getting my variable names and keywords in different color. It will be great, if i get the key words in bold. Can this be achieved  with prettify? I downloaded prettify.css from net and for js, i used the google-code-prettify link, you have given. prettyprint in prettify.css is not dealing with font explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not designed to change the look/format of text. It is designed to describe text. The best it can do, as you've discovered, is maintain spacing with the `<pre>` tag.

You cannot do it with just HTML. You must use one of the JS/CSS libs you mentioned for clientside syntax highlighting.

Comment: s i downloaded prettify.css from net and for js, i am using the autoloader google-code-prettify link.